# Mostrar Descrição ao invés de valor no angular

Tags: angularjs

Olá, estou aprendendo AngularJs e em meus exercícios me deparei com a seguinte questão: Como eu mostro uma descrição no lugar de um código. Por exemplo

```
$scope.aeronaves = [ cod_anv: '1', fabricante: '1' ];
$scope.fabricantes = [ cod_fab: '1', nome: 'Embraer' ];
```

Gostaria de ao invés de mostrar {{aeronaves.fabricante}} que será = 1, mostrar o nome do mesmo que está em outro array mas relacionado ao meu codigo.

Agradeço desde já,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro precisamos ajustar suas coleções, pois a declaração de objeto não está correta:

```
[ cod_anv: '1', fabricante: '1' ] // colchetes ([]) definem uma coleção de objetos,
                                  // porém objetos precisam ser declarados com chaves ({})
```

Segundo, criamos um mapa da coleção `fabricantes` indexado pela propriedade `cod_fab`.

Por último, instruímos o Angular para exibir o nome do fabricante de acordo com um índice pesquisado.

O código segue abaixo:

```js
function SampleController($scope) {
  
  $scope.aeronaves = [ {cod_anv: '1', fabricante: '1', modelo:'teste'}, 
                       {cod_anv: '2', fabricante: '2', modelo:'teste 2'},
                       {cod_anv: '3', fabricante: '1', modelo:'teste 3'},];
  $scope.fabricantes = [ {cod_fab: '1', nome: 'Embraer'},
                         {cod_fab: '2', nome: 'Boeing'} ];
  
  $scope.fabricantesMap = $scope.fabricantes.reduce(function (map, node) {
    map[node.cod_fab] = node;
    return map;
  }, {});
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="SampleController">
      
      <div ng-repeat='i in aeronaves'>
        {{i.cod_anv}} - {{i.modelo}} - {{fabricantesMap[i.fabricante].nome}}
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso! Obrigado pela aula!